# Plot scatter chart by using loop command

Tags: excel, vba

the main body of the programming is shown as below:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='7G'!$A$2"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='7G'!$B$2:$B$67"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='7G'!$N$2:$N$67"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "='7G'!$A$68"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='7G'!$B$68:$B$133"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='7G'!$N$68:$N$133"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "='7G'!$A$134"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = "='7G'!$B$134:$B199"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "='7G'!$N$134:$N$199"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "='7G'!$A$200"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).XValues = "='7G'!$B$200:$B$265"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Values = "='7G'!$N$200:$N$265"
```

mainly, need to plot 50 curves with above script in Excel.  Wonder if there is a way to simplify above script by using a loop statement since all series there have a formula to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Dim i, rowOff As Long
Dim cht As Chart

Set cht = ActiveChart

For i = 1 To 50
    rowOff = (i - 1) * 66 'calculate offset for this set
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = Sheets("7G").Range("a2").Offset(rowOff, 0).Value
        .XValues = Sheets("7G").Range("B2:B67").Offset(rowOff, 0).Value
        .Values = Sheets("7G").Range("N2:N67").Offset(rowOff, 0).Value
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks a lot for the help.  During the run got an error message of "Object variable or with block variable not set".  When debugging, got a highlight for "With .... End With" at " With...." line.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your chart embedded on a worksheet, or on a chart sheet?

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks a lot for the help.  my mistake: did not select an active chart.  Your script works greatly.

Comment: It would be better to not rely on a selected chart if this is part of a larger block of code - for example if you create and populate the chart in a single sub.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Dim Shs As Series
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

    Set Cht = ActiveChart
    Set Ws = Sheets("7G")
    n = 2
    With Cht
        For i = 1 To 50
            Set rngName = Ws.Range("a" & n)
            Set Shs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            With Shs
                .Name = rngName
                .XValues = rngName.Offset(, 1).Resize(66)
                .Values = rngName.Offset(, 3).Resize(66)
            End With
            n = n + 66
        Next i
    End with

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy, thanks for the help.  During the run, got error message of "Next without For" at the line of "Next Cht".  What is wrong?

Comment: @funny,  miss typing.  That is  End  with.